# Подскажите как правильно настроить nginx

Tags: nginx, httpd

Имеется vps сервер, на котором установлен **httpd**, **tomcat**, **ngin**x.
Настройки **httpd**:

```
ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"
Include conf.modules.d/*.conf
User apache
Group apache
ServerAdmin root@localhost

<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
</Directory>

DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
<Directory "/var/www">
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Настройки nginx:

```
# Server globals
user                    nginx;
worker_processes        auto;
error_log               /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid                     /var/run/nginx.pid;


# Worker config
events {
        worker_connections  1024;
        use                 epoll;
}


http {
    # Main settings
    sendfile                        on;
    tcp_nopush                      on;
    tcp_nodelay                     on;
    client_header_timeout           1m;
    client_body_timeout             1m;
    client_header_buffer_size       2k;
    client_body_buffer_size         256k;
    client_max_body_size            256m;
    large_client_header_buffers     4   8k;
    send_timeout                    30;
    keepalive_timeout               60 60;
    reset_timedout_connection       on;
    server_tokens                   off;
    server_name_in_redirect         off;
    server_names_hash_max_size      512;
    server_names_hash_bucket_size   512;


    # Mime settings
    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Proxy settings
    proxy_redirect      off;
    proxy_set_header    Host            $host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass_header   Set-Cookie;
    proxy_connect_timeout   90;
    proxy_send_timeout  90;
    proxy_read_timeout  90;
    proxy_buffers       32 4k;


    map $http_cookie $no_cache {
        default 0;
        ~SESS 1;
        ~wordpress_logged_in 1;
    }


    # Wildcard include
    include             /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

Собственно, вопрос:

Как мне настроить прокси, чтобы при запросе на

```
xxx.mydomen.ru/
```

он перенаправлялся на

```
mydomen.ru:8080/somesymbols
```

(Tomcat, просто на сервере крутится wordpress еще и запросы mydomen.ru идут туда)

Comment: Вам нужно перенаправить пользователя или прозрачно проксировать запросы внутри сервера?

Comment: Скорее всего внутри сервера (честно говоря, точно не знаю, но я пробовал добавить файл настроек в /sites/avaavailable/default.conf, но nginx упорно не видит эти настройки.

Comment: у вас в файле конфига nginx сайты грузятся из папки include             /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf, а не из вашей  /sites/avaavailable/